# Redis Queue Java Tutorial

Tags: java, redis

I'm new to redis. I searched in net , im not able to find suitable tutorial. I need to know whether its possible doing in **JAVA**? I need to store some data in redis Queue and i need to read the data in order user rest call. Is it possible? Is there any tutorial for this?

Answer (score 7):

Try [Redisson](https://redisson.org) - it allows to create distributed Java objects on top of Redis sever. Example with Queue:

```
Redisson redisson = Redisson.create();

RQueue<SomeObject> queue = redisson.getQueue("anyQueue");
queue.add(new SomeObject());
queue.peek();
queue.pool();

...

redisson.shutdown();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use Redis with Java. I recommended [Jedis](http://code.google.com/p/jedis/) which is Redis's Java Library.

You can also use Redis to build a Queue or Stack. See [here](http://redis.io/commands/rpoplpush).

Answer (score 1):

I have worked with jedis, a java client for redis. You can download **jedis 2.6.2** jar file and write programs in java that interact with redis.  In jedis, there are methods for redis commands- like set() method for set command, get() method for get command and so on.

here is one very simple code i made using jedis. it makes a connection to the redis server, sets a key and gets the same:

```
import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
public class SetGet {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Connecting to Redis on localhost
        Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
        // adding a new key
        jedis.set("key", "hello");
        // getting the key value
        System.out.println(jedis.get("key"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not actually queue mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use redis with java  with the help of a simple open source JPA compliant ORM library named [Kundera](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/).